# How can I debug this LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

How can I debug linq query? when query is too long

Comment: what's your question? The answer is most likely to split your query apart both for ease of debugging and readability's sake

Comment: [Debugging LINQ Queries](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/11/07/debugging-linq-queries.aspx)

Comment: @Vishal: Geez, you made the code even worse formatting it that way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debuggen is very limited with linq. See the link @JW shown in the comment.

But in you case you could split it up. It makes it's easier to see thats going on.

```
var tmpLst = panelInfo.AsEnumerable()
             .Where(panelModel =>
             panelModel.Field<string>(modelNumberColumnName) == solution.ModelNumber)
    .Select(panelModel => panelModel.Field<int>(voltageListSupportedColumnName))
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

foreach(var item in tmpLst)
{
       voltagesSupported.AddRange(
            ModelInfoController.VoltageInfos[(uint)item]
                .Select(voltage => (int)voltage)
                .ToList()

}
```